# webpack does not find other than style.css file

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I am trying to run tutorial project with webpack from [here](https://angular.io/guide/webpack)

It works fine when I have only style.css file. But when I create suppose x1.css file , it does not compile it in final bundle. So is there anything missing in tutorial itself?

These are my webpack files.

webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [{
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }
                }, 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'errors-only',
        open: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you configured your CSS loader and imported that CSS file?

Comment: Yes I have configured it and loaded css files as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add something like this into the configuration file:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
}
```